# Why won't my jPlayer work in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jplayer

I'm making an audio player for my music blog that I run, but I can't seem to get jPlayer to work properly on my website. Right now, I have it set so that only admins can view the player (since it's not working), but I made a little test website so that you can see what I mean too.

The player works fine in Firefox, but won't work correctly on Chrome. I have a feeling that it has something to do with the flash fallback that it uses for Firefox, but I don't see why it wouldn't work on Chrome too. It just does not seem to want to load/stream the songs at all.

I have a few functions that I made so the songs can be added dynamically on whichever page you are viewing. I believe I am setting up everything correctly. I use an array for the title of the song and the URL to the MP3, and they are added dynamically by WordPress. Every time a new song is added, I call the JavaScript function add_song below...

```
function add_song(title, mp3)
{
    theTitles[index] = title;
    theMP3s[index] = mp3;
    index++;
}
```

Then for the document.ready function, I set up my jPlayer by using another function that I made called get_playlist();

```
function get_playlist()
{
    var playlist = new Array();

    for(var i = 0; i < theTitles.length; i++)
    {
        playlist[i] = {title: theTitles[i], mp3: theMP3s[i]};
    }
    return playlist;
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    var playlist = get_playlist();
    new jPlayerPlaylist({
        jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1",
        oggSupport:false
    }, playlist, {
        swfPath: "/js",
        supplied: "mp3",
        wmode: "window"
    });
});
```

I have a feeling that I'm missing something simple as to why it would work on Firefox and not Chrome, but I can't figure out what it is. Here is my [url](http://www.startingtofeelit.com/text.php) to the test site so you can view the player yourself if you have any questions.

Thanks guys and gals!

Comment: Not sure what the issue is that you are having. I opened it in chrome and can play it. It does look messed up but I don't think that's the issue you are referencing here.

Comment: Have you checked your MIME types?